# Running the same rspec tests on multiple routes with sinatra

Tags: rspec, sinatra, dry

My sinatra application has a security method which runs at the start of some routes. I want to run the same set of authentication rspec tests against each of the routes which I need to be secure, but I don't want to repeat myself in rspec. How should I do this?

```
helpers do
  def requires_auth!
    # stuff
  end
end

post '/object' do
  requires_auth!

  # stuff
end

put '/object' do
  requires_auth!

  # stuff
end

get '/object' do
  # doesn't require auth

  # stuff
end
```

My spec currently looks like this, and looks very repetitive.

```
describe 'The post request' do
  it 'should fail if auth token is invalid'
  it 'should fail if auth token has expired'

  it 'should pass if <other stuff>'
end

describe 'The put request' do
  it 'should fail if auth token is invalid'
  it 'should fail if auth token has expired'

  it 'should pass if <more other stuff>'
end

describe 'The get request' do
  it 'should pass if <other stuff yet again>'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have RTFM! Looks like this is exactly what `shared_examples` is used for. If you think there's a better way that's specific to Sinatra do post away though!